# Inotifywait for large directories

Tags: callback, inotify

In the inotifywait man changes the following is stated

> -r, --recursive  Watch  all  subdirectories of any directories passed as arguments.  Watches will be set up recursively to an unlimited
>   depth.  Symbolic links are not tra‐versed.  Newly created
>   subdirectories will also be watched.
>
> Warning: If you use this option while watching the root directory of
>   a large tree, **it may take quite a while until all inotify  watches 
>   are  established**,  and  events will not be received in this time. 
>   Also, since one inotify watch will be established per subdirectory, it
>   is possible that the maximum amount
>                 of inotify watches per user will be reached.  The default maximum is 8192; it can be increased by writing to
>   /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches.

I take this to mean that every time `inotifywait` is called, there is a delay for large directories. Therefore, constantly monitoring a large directory with monitor function like so

```
inotifywait -m /home/user/Documents
```

is more efficient than manually looping through the directory like so (from an example in the man pages)

```
while inotifywait /home/user/Documents; do
 #Do Something for each file change
done
```

as every iteration of the while loop you have to set up inotifywait again. But with the first option, I can't execute based on the return. Ideally what I want is a callback function like so

```
inotifywait -m --callback ./callback.sh /home/user/Documents
```

so `callback.sh` gets called each time with the return value of `inotifywait`. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe it like:

```
inotifywait -m /my/directory | while read LINE; do ./do_something.sh $LINE; done
```

Keep in mind that you get many events for certain operations, each of which will trigger the launch of your script.

You can also use perl or some other language to use the API directly, which gives you tons of flexibility.

Comment: I have never used Perl. I noticed a lot of the examples use C, but I prefer to use shell whenever possible.

Comment: There's always the chance to filter the events using the `-e` switch of the command, and/or having do_something.sh grep the `$LINE` for the relevant ones.