# Using inotify to keep track of all files in a system

Tags: database, file, inotify

## Question:

Can `inotify` be used to reliably record files in a [linux] system?

## Details:

I am attempting to use `inotifywait` to track users movements (currently using bash, but it has been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098954/inotifywait-for-large-directories) that I migrate to a scripting language). Ultimately I want to add new files to a database upon creation (`create`, `moved_from`), update existing rows in a database upon file modification (`modify`, `attrib`, `move_to`), and finally remove a row upon file deletion (`delete`). I am, however, running into many problems as even an action as seemingly simple as *save*, generates many inotifywait messages. Observe the following commands and their output (note, the use of `/home/user/` is purely for example purposes):

## Examples:

**Example 1: Listen for file creation:**

```
$ inotifywait -mr /home/user/ -e create  --format %w:%f:%e:%T --timefmt %T
```

**Touch:**

```
$touch test.txt
/home/user/:test.txt:CREATE:21:35:30
```

**Open a new file with vim then issue :w command:**

```
$vim test2.txt
/home/user/:test2.txt:CREATE:21:35:30
```

**Open an existing file with vim then issue :w command:**

```
$vim test2.txt
/home/user/:4913:CREATE:21:35:30
/home/user/:test2.txt:CREATE:21:35:30
```

**Open a new file with gedit then click save:**

```
$gedit test3.txt
/home/user/:test3.txt~:CREATE:21:35:30
```

**Open an existing file with gedit then click save:**

```
$gedit test3.txt
/home/user/:.goutputstream-HN3ZDW:CREATE:21:35:30
/home/user/:test3.txt~:CREATE:21:35:30
```

Note that not only are  two new files displayed as having ben created (`4913` and `.goutputstream-HN3ZDW`), but also that the only file being created is `test3.txt~` and **not** `test3.txt`, even though the file `test3.txt` is created when checked with the `ls` command. For completeness, here is the above example, but with a few more options.

**Example 1: Listen for file creation, modification, deltion, and movement:**

```
$ inotifywait -mr /home/user/ -e create -e modify -e delete -e moved_to -e moved_from --format %w:%f:%e:%T --timefmt %T
```

**Touch:**

```
$touch test.txt
/home/user/:test.txt:CREATE:21:35:30
```

**Open a new file with vim then issue :w command:**

```
$vim test2.txt
/home/user/:test2.txt:CREATE:22:12:32
```

**Open an existing file with vim then issue :w command:**

```
$vim test2.txt
/home/user/:4913:CREATE:22:04:35
/home/user/:4913:DELETE:22:04:35
/home/user/:test2.txt:MOVED_FROM:22:04:35
/home/user/:test2.txt~:MOVED_TO:22:04:35
/home/user/:test2.txt:CREATE:22:04:35
/home/user/:test2.txt~:DELETE:22:04:35
```

**Open a new file with gedit then click save:**

```
$gedit test3.txt
/home/user/:test3.txt~:CREATE:21:35:30
```

**Open an existing file with gedit then click save:**

```
$gedit test3.txt
/home/user/:.goutputstream-0WQ2DW:CREATE:22:06:34
/home/user/:test3.txt~:CREATE:22:06:34
/home/user/:.goutputstream-0WQ2DW:MOVED_FROM:22:06:34
/home/user/:test3.txt:MOVED_TO:22:06:34
```

Basically my question is "is it possible to use `inotify` to update a file in a database"? For example, if a user edits a file and saves it, I want it to be reflected in the database as an update to that file, and not a brand new file replacing a completely different file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it's a suggestion pointing me in a different direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inotify` tells you what happens like it happens.

Gedit, like most editors, saves by first writing a temporary file then moving that file into place. This avoids overwriting the file with a half-written version in case the editor or the whole system crashes while the file is being written. Vim takes a different approach (this can be configured, I won't go into details here — see e.g. [why inode value changes when we edit in “vi” editor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36467/why-inode-value-changes-when-we-edit-in-vi-editor)): it first creates a temporary backup file, then writes the new file.

If you want these to be recorded as a single editing event, you'll have to perform some pattern recognition on the even log. A create-write-move sequence that replaces an existing file and a create-move-create delete sequence like vim's would be the archetypal patterns. Note that the pattern might be interleaved with other events.

I have a suspicion that there's a better way to do what you want to do, but I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you're trying to log user actions, you have already found a way, but there are simpler ways: [loggedfs or the audit subsystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file). If you want to keep a backup of all file versions, either hook up the editor to a version control system (this lets users control what gets backed up) or use a [versioning filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_filesystem) such as [copyfs](http://n0x.org/copyfs/). You can even store the files in the database directly, by using a filesystem like [mysqlfs](http://mysqlfs.sourceforge.net/) or [postgresqlfs](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresqlfs.git;a=summary) (admittedly neither project looks maintained).

Comment: Thanks for the info. wrt. the pattern recognition, I am worried that it won't be 100% reliable. What I am trying to do is store all user and group permission in MySQL, and all the file locations as well (not the actual files) and I want all updates in the system to be reflected in the database. I will have a look at mysqlfs.

Comment: @puk Ok, then mysqlfs, copyfs and the like won't help you. Loggedfs or audit logs are the way to go (they're easier to exploit than inotify logs). You get the events as they happen. You're putting high-level meanings on these events, but at the filesystem level, these meanings have no counterpart: the notion of “saving a file” is known to the editor, but the filesystem only sees open, write, rename, etc. Since the high-level meanings come from you, you need to do the analysis to recognize meaningful patterns in the actual events.

Comment: thank god, the mysqlfs page looked like it was coded in 1992. I will have a look at loggedfs and audit. When you say "logs" I am assuming you mean signals from `inotifywait` right? Or do you mean actually writing to a log file?

Comment: just add ``--exclude '/\..+'`` and inotify will ignore the temporary *.goutputstream* files