# Watching a file for changes in Linux

Tags: linux, file, search, inotify

## Question:

Is there any way to track the progress of a file in Linux (ie. new file/save file)?

## Details:

I am aware of [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) which can be used to track entire folders for file creation, deletion, and modification. However, those are very low level. Text editors often when saving a file, write the modified buffer a temporary location, then move it and overwrite the original file. This would be seen by inotify as a `CREATE` and a `MOVE` when what I want is a `MODIFY`.

It seems counter intuitive to me that every time a file is saved it would be interpreted as a new file. Is there any identifying value of a file I can use to distinguish between creating a fresh new file and saving an existing file? Another way to ask this question is: "How do programs such as [Beagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_%28software%29), [Spotlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_%28software%29), [Windows Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search), and [Google Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Desktop) get around this problem"?

## Goal:

Here is a good way to describe what I want: Using `Vim`, if I open a file and save it (`:w`), that file will get written to a temporary file and then moved over to the original file, tricking `inotify` into believing that a completely new file was created and then used to overwrite the original file. However, if add a file to subversion (`svn`), then open that file with `Vim` and save it (`:w`), `svn` will know that the saved file is actually a modified file and not a new one. How does `svn` know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain while new or a save might look the same in Linux. One big difference in linux from windows is that no file creation time is stored with the inode, only access, modify (file content change), and change (inode change) time is stored. So unless you keep the information elsewhere such as inside the file itself as metadata, you cannot tell if the file was just created or just changed.

Comment: Even if the creation time was stored, wouldn't it still get overwritten by the text editor in this case? What if the text editor instead saved files like so `cp a.txt a.txt~; rm a.txt; cp a.txt~ a.txt`? Is there any way around this that you can think of?

Comment: My problem isn't that I don't know when the file was created, but that programs like `vim` write to a temporary file then move it over to the original file, so it's impossible to tell when a file is being overwritten completely, or just haphazardly modified.

Comment: True, temporary files makes it hard to tell. Is your concern security or something else? If security then programs like tripwire may help, although I do not know exactly how they determine when the file changes either.

Comment: Please see the example I added above. Security is not an issue right now. I am adding files to a database and I want to be able to tell when a new file is created (in which case I add a new row) or when a file is saved 100,000 times (in which case I do NOT want to add 100,000 new rows)

Comment: svn keeps its own metadata and compares the file content between the repository and the working directory. so to do the same, you would, before inserting the record, to do something similar, to check if the row already exist. is your filename unique or at least the full path? you need to store a unique key of some sort to identify a new file.

Comment: I thought of that, but what constitutes a "unique key" for a file? When one modifies a file, anything unique about it has been changed. Is there anything unique in the inode? Is there a Linux package that modifies the inodes in a way similar to how ACLs modify basic linux permissions?

Comment: yes, that will be inode. if you only insert a row when there is a new file (inode) created, then you would have to store all the nodes somewhere, and then when you detect a file, you will compare with your db and see if the inode is there or not. this will aslo avoid inserting a row because of link creation. without knowing your exact storage system i think this is the best i can come up with, though the problem sounds quite interesting and challenging.

Comment: actually, inode number (i-number) may be monotonically increasing (not sure if this applies to all file systems), so actually you may only have to store the current largest inode number and make things much easier. you may have to look into the source code to be sure though.

Comment: forgive me, but I fail to see how the inode will aid me in detecting when overwrites are actually temporary files in disguise. What I was thinking was to have a database of file actions (`create`, `modify`, `move`), and when there is a `move`, I go through the trace and see if the `move_to` is the same as a possible `move_from` (and the `move_from` file was not edited in between), then I can safely say that was a `save` operation. Although a DB might not be the best choice as this would be a recursive search

Comment: See here for further information as to what lies at the heart of my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/10544487/654789

Comment: You are right, to deal with temporary files, you have to do something yourself. Not sure if trace is the best way, but if you know temporarily file creation location say /var/tmp and /tmp, you can also just ignore these locations when the file path are there. Generally application store temporary files in specific places.

Comment: Vim for example uses temp file `4913`, but I would rather have a general solution. Although I wouldn't put it past some program to split a file, write it to two swap files then merge them back to the original file...

Comment: @johnshen64 Reading file data should not be nessecary. If open(2) sends a system-wide signal, file system data is not involved at all.

Answer (score 1):

johnshen64 answered you why you don't see it as modified. Regarding SVN (or Git), they would recognize the file as modified because they keep a "key" of already managed files.

So for your database, you would need to do the same. For instance you could use a simple numeric hash from the filename (or the filename itself but string comparison is slow) and do a rapid query to see if he file is already manage before adding it.

Comment: what you're describing, checking to see if a file already exists in my DB, doesn't solve my problem: distinguishing between deleting/overwriting a file, and editing an existing file indirectly by making a swap file and overwriting the original file with it.

Comment: So you need to make a difference between a new file with the same filename and an updated file (that was updated using a temporary file). I did not get that from your question. You probably need to look in the possible metadata you can attached to a file in an ext* filesystem, these metadata should be replicated by the temporary swap while editing. Or security system like SELinux would not work!

Comment: YES! Also, yes, metadata is exactly what I am looking for, but I don't know where to begin (is it even possible?) Your last sentence " Or security system like SELinux would not work" is a little vague. Could you clarify please.

Comment: You have to ask another question regarding this. I know this is a feature of file systems on Linux, I don't know how to use it. As for SELinux, to enforce rules it is labeling files (using metadata) instead of using pathname as AppArmor does. It means that if the file is deleted and replaced, then the label is lost and SELinux will detect it, whereas AppArmor would not notice it. On the other hand, when upgrading software you need to relabel the file with SELinux, but this is not needed with AppArmor. See for instance: https://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/whitepapers/Filesystem_Labeling_SELinux.pdf